# Creating a Credential Provider using Eclipse CDT

Tags: windows, visual-c++, winapi, credential-providers

I am currently trying to develop a Credential Provider for Windows 7 32Bit. I am currently using Eclipse CDT to acchieve this. After installing the Windows SDK and setting up CDT correctly I was able to compile and link the neccessary dlls (was quite a hasle and I'm not 100% positiv it's working as expected, but at least he throws no errors). When I now try to install the credential provider it throws me an msvcr90.dll missing error. I got around that one by finding the correct version of the dll on the net (note that the version of msvcr90.dll it needed was not supplied in any version of redistributable, so no need to point them out, I've been through that already). Now that I installed it and copied the msvcr90.dll into the system32 folder, I start to get a R6034 Runtime Error ("... attempt to load C runtime library incorecctly...").

Haven't been able to resolve that until now. I tried it the other way around by creating a static dll instead of a shared dll. All that happens when I try it with that is that the Credential Provider is not even loading during system start.

Has anyone had similar problems or knows how to solve this? My last resort would be to somehow get VS, but I'd like to stay with CDT for now, as I am not realy sure this is related to the problem.

For the record, I am currently just trying to get the standard SampleCredentialProvider tutorial to work. No code written by myself is used, so that shouldn`t be the cause of the problems.

**Edit:**
For an update, I gave up on this undertaking to get CDT to compile a working Credential Provider. Since I'm a student and I'm doing this for a thesis I just downloaded VS and it worked like a charm without much hassle etc. To much of a waste of time to try and get it to work without getting any output as to whats going wrong etc. I'm leaving this question open for discussion if someone ever has the will to get this to work. Right now I don't have time to deal with it. For the Record the most important libraries for the linking are: advapi32.lib, ole32.lib, user32.lib, secur32.lib and shlwapi.lib (had to find this out via trial and error...)

Comment: This is a great undertaking. Please consider posting your Eclipse project when its done (at least the one that builds the sample CP)

Comment: I gave up on this for now as it seems kind of overkill to try and figure out whats not working etc. The main problem seems to be that CDT basicly does not support every needed feature in order to compile a Credential Provider.

Answer (score 0):

You basically have two choices :

1. Install the [Visual Studio 2008 runtime side by side](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326922), basically running `Vcredist_x86.exe`.
2. Make the static build work.

Both options have their [pros and cons](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22642/What-Every-Computer-Programmer-Should-Know-About-W#CodeReuse), but since a Credential provider must be installed by an administrator, and considering the trouble you already have gone through, I would keep going with option 1.

I'm not shure the vcredist is included in the platform sdk. Here is a [direct link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29).